# API Gateway does not pass Authorization header to Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to use SAM to configure an api gateway and a lambda. However, looking at the event passed to the Lambda, Authorization header is missing. Authorization is suppose to be the JWT from Cognito. When using standard Cloudformation templates, this token is passed as part of the event.

I cannot find anything in SAM documentation or examples, that points me on how to solve this issue.

Comment: Have you actually configured your REST api to require authorization and then deployed your api?

Comment: Yes, we did. Authorization works and headers work just fine when deploying with standard Cloudformation templates. So I am very confident that the set up is correct. The header is not passed only when using SAM template. Which leads me to believe this is a SAM template issue.

Comment: If you've isolated the issue to the template, can you post the template section.